# Py4JJavaError Spark in vscode

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

I have this error when i run this code in vscode, i think the problem is related to:

Java Version Compatibility: O
Java Environment Setup:
Dependencies:
PySpark Configuration

````
data = [1,2,3,4,5]
for i in range(1,5):
    rdd = spark.sparkContext.parallelize(data, i)
    print('partition: ', rdd.glom().collect())
    print('division: ', rdd.reduce(lambda a,b: a/b))```
````

[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R2bNO.png)

I see that its related to java but i have java installed, also i can run this code on databricks with no problem.
I dont know if java most be installed differently or do i need some other packages o maybe another version of pyspark, im using now pyspaek 3.4.1.

I dont know the source of this problem.

Answer (score 0):

this solution worked for me.
this error getting because of pyspark and python connection not established correctly.

Solution: set PYSPARK_PYTHON environment variable to python.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/76042851/9643742

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).